# Prevent adding new point in openlayers 3 draw mode

Tags: openlayers-3

When a user is drawing a polygon on a map in draw mode in openlayers 3, I am detecting whenever they have any lines that self-intersect, and when this is the case, I want to prevent them from drawing any new points until the lines no longer intersect.  I am able to detect when lines are intersecting, but I am having difficulty disabling the user from being able to click the map and putting down more points when the intersecting lines condition is true.  Does anyone know how I could do this with openlayers 3?  Thank you!

Comment: How about a jsfiddle? It gives more context to our help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating a tiny no click div that followed around the mouse.  When I detected that two lines were intersecting I increased the z-index of this div above the map using jquery so the map could no longer be clicked on.